# Redefine the printnames command so as to change the font?

Tags: biblatex, citing

the `\printnames` command produces one of the following output:

```
John Smith
John Smith and Paul Winston
John Smith et al.
```

However I don't want to print the first names of the authors. That is, the desired output is:

```
Smith
Smith and Winston
Smith et al.
```

Also, I get the authors' names in *small caps* font, which is not what I want.

[EDIT] Concerning the *small caps* font problem, I think it comes from the style file I use. I tried `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}` as suggested by @moewe, but it didn't help.

As for the context of this problem, I am trying to make my own citation command.
I edited a local `biblatex.cfg' file with the following content:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}{}{%
    \printnames[default]{author}%
}{}{}
```

My `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=authoryear-comp,
    natbib=true,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{S10,
  author = {Smith, John and Winston, Paul},
  date = {2010},
  title = {Some title 1},
}
@misc{S11,
  author = {Smith, John and Winston, Paul},
  date = {2011},
  title = {Some title 2},
}
@misc{S12,
  author = {Smith, John and Winston, Paul and Porter, Mark},
  date = {2012},
  title = {Some title 3},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One author: \mycite{S10} 
    \item Two authors: \mycite{S11} 
    \item Three authors: \mycite{S12}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: A MWE would also be greatly appreciated ;-) See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Without an MWE we can just guess ... Normally the names are not in small caps, but I seem to remember that the French language file changes last names to mall caps. Does `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}` help?

Comment: Thx for considering my question. I'll be back in 5 minutes with a MWE.

Comment: Why do you use `\printnames` in the first place? It is more of an low-level command for styles than an actual document-level macro? To change the output format, you will have to define a name format.

Comment: Where did you try `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}`. It should work if you use it in the preamble of your document. Please consider posting a full MWE. As it stands now the three lines of code do not give much more information that before.

Comment: I tried in the preamble of the document but it did not work...

Comment: That MWE does not produce author names in small caps here. Instead of `\printnames[default]{author}%` you probably want `\printnames[labelname]{author}%` -- which will not always give you only the last name, if authors need to be disambiguated a first name or initial is added.

Comment: It works! Thanks. And by the way, if I write `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}` just before the `printnames` command I get a normal font (and no first name)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a custom citing command, you'll probably want to use the `labelname` format for names. You probably do not even want to print the `author`, but the `labelname` field (the difference being that the `labelname` field might contain the editor of a work if no author is given).

Solution to print `labelname`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}{}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
}{}{}
```

Print `author` with labelname format (not the best of ideas)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}{}{%
    \printnames[labelname]{author}%
}{}{}
```